# CKEditor.replace keeps giving errors

Tags: ckeditor, joomla2.5, php-5.3

System information is: PHP Version-5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26; Web Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu); WebServer to PHP Interface - apache2handler; Version Joomla! 2.5.28 Stable [ Ember ] 10-December-2014 15:00 GMT; Joomla! Platform Version-Joomla Platform 11.4.0 Stable. still, my:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );</script>
```

keeps giving errors:

```
VM3764:84 GET domain.com/index.php/apps/config.js?t=G87E 404 (Not Found)
VM3764:84 GET domain.com/index.php/apps/skins/moono/editor.css?t=G87E 
VM3764:84 GET domain.com/index.php/apps/lang/en.js?t=G87E 404 (Not Found)
CKEDITOR.env.ie.e.$.onerror @ VM3764:232
VM3764:84 GET domain.com/index.php/apps/lang/en.js?t=G87E 404 (Not Found)
CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire @ VM3764:12
CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire @ VM3764:13
CKEDITOR.env.ie.e.$.onerror @ VM3764:232
VM3764:230 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined
```

the full code involved is simply this:

```
echo"<script type='text/javascript' src='https://fabrik.smartstartinc.net/ncpcphp/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'></script>";
echo"<div name='editor1' id='editor1' rows='10' cols='80'>replace this div with CKEditor.</div>";
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );</script>";
```

using CKEditors [tried multiple, same result]: standard[4.0, 4.5.11, 4.6.2], and full 4.6.2]. very stumped, errors persist. ideas?

Answer (score 0):

this code can be in the  html head area; or here i put it just before the PHP scripting a series of case stmts - got me to where the CKEditor appears above the div area:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH ='https and domain URL here/ckeditor/';</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https and domain URL here/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https and domain URL here/ckeditor/config.js'></script>
```

and the existing div code used to accept the new CKEditor tool bar:

```
echo "<div id = '$val' class = 'DetailBox' style='display:none; height:415px'></div>";
```

and finally, the replace function:

```
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>CKEDITOR.replace( '$val');</script>";
```

the basepath statement was the final piece that fit it all together.